# Merge [tag:power-delivery] with [tag:usb-power-delivery]

Tags: discussion, tags

[power-delivery](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/power-delivery) and [usb-power-delivery](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/usb-power-delivery) seem synonymous. Let's merge them?

Answer (score 2):

Makes sense. I'll give it a week to see if there's any objections and make it so. If I forget (this happens!) feel free to ping.

Edit:
Merge done. Had a bit of an oopsie, but all sorted.

Comment: ..... I got bitten by "confusing merge options" again https://superuser.com/tags/usb-power-delivery/synonyms synonymn needs upvotes :/

Comment: And upvotes require having enough score... Great. https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaoWX.png

Comment: .... Ok, I'll have  to ask for help at this point :D